# Index match on row and subrow combination

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having a table where two rows describe one entity.

My data looks like that:

[image]

Btw I uploaded [my image here](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=807fbed), because I had some issues with the uploader...

I was thinking about an `index-match` combination, but this does only work with one row.

Any suggestion, how to make multiple matching of columns?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This formula returns the result you show in your screenshot. Starting in C13, copy across and down

=SUMIFS($7:$7,$2:$2,C$12,$3:$3,$B13)

You could also use Index/Match, but don't use whole rows in the inner Index, because that will slow down your workbook.

=INDEX($7:$7,MATCH(C$12&$B13,INDEX($A$2:$J$2&$A$3:$J$3,0),0))

[image]